# SharePoint Calculated Column Formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns, sharepoint-designer

Here's my formula:

=IF(Status="Completed",IF([JCN Type]="EDLM","UDLM",[Date Completed]+10),IF([JCN Type]="EA","TA",[Date Completed]+15))

I also want to have to be 10 or 15 work days but not really sure how to tie that in.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found [a similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/868266/sharepoint-calculated-column-if-statements.html) that you  created on Microsoft Q&A community, the solution has been delivered, post it here for other users' reference.

From JinweiLi-MSFT:
*Please try to use this:*

```
 =IF(Status="Completed",IF(OR([JCN Type]="EDLM",[JCN Type]="UDLM"),[Date Completed]+10,IF(OR([JCN Type]="EA",[JCN Type]="TA"),[Date Completed]+15)),"")
```